# Adding a sequence constraint in ortools

Tags: python, or-tools

I am looking for a way to add a special sequence constraint using Google's ortools as part of a shift scheduling program.
I have shifts of two kinds: D and E.
I need to be able to prevent certain persons from getting a part of a sequence of shifts.
For instance if I have the following shift list:

`D D E E E D`

Bob should only get non consecutive shifts.

Alice on the other hand should only get non consecutive shifts unless it is an E type shift and than she can only get all the consecutive E shifts.

Good example:

`D:Alice, D:Bob, E:Alice, E:Alice, E:Alice, D:Bob`

Bad example:

`D:Alice, D:Bob, E:Alice, E:Bob, E:Alice, D:Bob`

Comment: Can you add some code? Are shift kinds also decision variables? I would say that you need something like `model.Add(shift[d][alice] == 1).OnlyEnforceIf([shift[d][e], shift[d +1][e]])`

Comment: Or `AddBoolOr([shift[d][alice]]).OnlyEnforceIf([shift[d][e], shift[d +1][e]])` or `AddBoolOr([shift[d][alice], shift[d][e].Not(), shift[d +1][e].Not()])`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am using this code: https://github.com/Dalamar42/or-shifty/blob/master/or_shifty/constraints.py

But I am not sure I to merge your suggestion with the type of programing done there.